# Destructuring Korean characters

Tags: javascript, unicode, character-encoding, cjk

What I'm trying to do is get a Korean verb or adjective and turn it to its dictionary form. So let's say that someone typed '추워요', which is the adjective for cold. Its dictionary form is '춥다'. Is there a way that I can do something like:

> "Hey, if it ends in '워요' append a 'ㅂ' to the character right before it".

Specifically that part of appending, is there a way to do something like that?

Like 가 + ㅆ = 갔.

I'm using Javascript but I'm open to try another language if it's easier to do it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because linguistic enquiries could be answered rather at https://korean.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @JosefZ This is an English question about parsing Korean with computers, not a Korean question. It's perfectly fine here. José Carlos: this is usually the domain of a lexer/parser. So a quick google yields https://github.com/l337Rooster/Korean-language-parser which in turn should be plenty of information for you to take it from there (including contacting actual people who did this already). Because even if you're working in some language, the best solutiosn are not necessarily in that language, and building simple exec based bridges is really easy =)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: I believe this is not a matter of the programming language, but how you deal with encoding.

Unlike another alphabetic language, Korean Hangul has a different system since Hangul is made up of sub-alphabets (자모, not sure how linguistically expressed).
And there are two different methods to encode Hangul into a string: Combined Hangul and Completed Hangul (조합형, 완성형).

Combined Hangul encodes each sub-alphabets (ㄱ, ㄴ, ㄷ, ..., ㅏ, ㅑ, ㅓ, ㅕ, ...), and combines those parts into complete letters.
Completed Hangul encodes every(or often being used) Hangul letter (가, 나, 다).
Combined Hangul has more flexible, but completed Hangul has more efficient performance-wise.
Mostly—especially in a web environment—combined Hangul is most likely being used since it is smaller and faster.

Since you need to deal with each sub-alphabets, you need to research ways to deal with the Combined Hangul system. You may need to convert Completed Hangul into Combined Hangul if necessary.